# The primitive type double of a does not have a field

Tags: java

Sorry for this basic question, I have tried to check other answers on SO but they haven't been convincing. My code is plain and simple but I do not understand why do I have compiling errors.

Can someone explain this in layman terms? It would be very helpful.

```
public class gravityCalculator 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double g= -9.81;
    double u= 0.0;
    double t= 10.0;
    double x_i =0;
    double s;
    double a=0;
    if(a<=0){
        a=g;
    }
    //System.out.println(a);
    s= 0.5+a.t^2+u.t+x_i;
}
}
```

Error Trace

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The primitive type double of a does not have a field t
    The primitive type double of u does not have a field t
```

Edit: This question can also be useful to know about the difference between Datatype and an Object.
Solution : s= 0.5*a*t * t+u*t+x_i;

Comment: what does `s= 0.5+a.t^2+u.t+x_i;` suppose to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplication symbol in Java is `*`, not `.`. Also, Java does not have an exponentiation operator (and `^` means something different than what you want). Correct syntax for what you're trying to do:

```
s = 0.5 + a*t*t + u*t + x_i;
```

Here I just multiplied `t*t` to get `t`<sup>2</sup>. In general, exponentiation can be calculated with the `Math.pow()` method.

EDIT: Assuming that you want to calculate position at a given time `t` for a given start position `x_i`, velocity `v` and acceleration `a`, you not only need to correct the syntax as above, but you also need to correct the formula:

```
s = 0.5*a*t*t + u*t + x_i;
```

(The 0.5 needs to be a coefficient of *at*<sup>2</sup>, not an added term.)

Comment: Thanks Ted, I did not complete the expression due to the error but I have fixed the physics formula too in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In your expression `s= 0.5+a.t^2+u.t+x_i;` there is a part `u.t` that confused the compiler.

It supposed that `u` had a public property (field) with name `t`, but it did not. So you get the error.

`u` has primitive type double. It is not an object, so it does not have any properties.

Rewrite your expression like that: `s = 0.5 + a*t*t + u*t + x_i;`

Comment: It's not `x - i`; the variable name is `x_i`.

Comment: @PhaniMadhav you are very welcome :) Check this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Answer (score -1):

It's the line  s= 0.5 + **a.t**

what were you trying to achieve there? perhaps multiplication? in that case it's asterisk:

```
0.5 + a * t
```

Answer (score -1):

`s= 0.5+a.t^2+u.t+x_i;`
You are writing `.` instead of `*` for multiplication. `.` is used to denote methods of fields of the object and primitive objects have no methods or attributes.

Edit: `^` is used as XOR. To square, you have to multiply t*t or use java.lang.Math.pow (I would not recommend using this one as it is way slower.).

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in this part `t^2` in java to make a power use [Math.pow()](http://www.w3api.com/w/index.php5?title=Java:Math.pow%28%29), to get t^2 use `Math.pow(t,2)`, also, to multiply in java you have to use `*` operator instead of `.` that means object property or attribute, so your complete sentence must be:

Also, to make a correct calculation you must think in operations order, mutiply and divide goes first, so you have to be carefull with parenthesis to get correct result!

```
s= (0.5+a)*Math.pow(t,2)+u*(t+x_i);
```